# junit5 create temp file

Tags: java, junit5

I wrote a unit test with junit 5 that tests some file system logic for which I need a folder and some files. I found the [TempDir](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html) annotation in the documentation and used that to create a folder, into which I saved some files. Something like:

```
@TempDir
static Path tempDir;

static Path tempFile;

// ...

@BeforeAll
public static void init() throws IOException {
    tempFile = Path.of(tempDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath(), "test.txt");
    if (!tempFile.toFile().createNewFile()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create file " + tempFile.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }
    // ...
}
```

In junit4 it was possible to use [TemporaryFolder#newFile(String)](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html#newFile(java.lang.String)). This doesn't seem to be around in junit5.

Am I missing something? It works so I suppose that's fine but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to create a new file directly with the junit 5 api.

Comment: I think your way is absolutely correct. I also used this in a similar way like in point 4.2 on https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-temporary-directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simplify the amount of typing for getting temp files if you make use of the built in methods of `Files`. This is a more concise definition to provide `tempFile` which should give similar error handling:

```
@TempDir
static Path tempDir;
static Path tempFile;

@BeforeAll
public static void init() throws IOException {
    tempFile = Files.createFile(tempDir.resolve("test.txt"));
}
```

Ensure that you have a recent version of JUNIT5. The test below should pass, but fails in some older versions of JUNIT which do not generate unique values of `@TempDir` for fields `tempDir` and `mydir`:

```
@Test void helloworld(@TempDir Path mydir) {
    System.out.println("helloworld() tempDir="+tempDir+" mydir="+mydir);
    assertFalse(Objects.equals(tempDir, mydir));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown here (https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-temporary-directory) you can either annotate a File or a Path with `@TempDir`, and write to the designated File using `java.nio.Files#write` with a `Path` for its target argument.