# How to create a Path to a non existent file

Tags: java, path, nio

How can I create a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) to a file which is guaranteed not to exist?

I thought about using an ["impossible"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75135/41094) path name, such as:

```
Path path = Path.of("/nonexistent");
```

But somebody could create such a file, making my code fail.

**Update**

I have written a method which accepts a `Path` and then tries to read from the underlying file, and now I am writing a unit test to make sure I have correctly handled non existing files.

I wish to make my unit test robusts, without risking random failures.

Comment: A path is just that: a path. We can use [`Files::exists`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) and/or [`Files:notExists`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) to check whether a file exists under the given `Path`.

Comment: For completeness sake: A directory is considered a file in this context.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What would be its purpose?   Would this precede a write  operation?  Please provide some use cases.

Comment: If something is a valid path, there is no guarantee it did not exist in the past or won't exist in the future. The only thing you can do is check if a path doesn't exist right now. What are you trying to achieve? This sounds like X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary directory for the test, then any file path under that directory won't exist - use that for your tests.

If you use JUNIT5 have a look at [@TempDir](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-built-in-extensions-TempDirectory) which sets up a new empty directory for a test case. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686024/junit5-create-temp-file/66760781#66760781).

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution:

1. [Create a new, temporary file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)).
2. [Immediately delete it](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)).

I would not use this if security depended on it but, for testing purposes, I believe this almost guarantees that the file does not exist.

```
Path path = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
Files.delete(path);
```

Comment: You could of course add `Assertions.assertTrue(Files.notExists(path));` before your call but I think you are correct to assume not needed - as `Files.delete` should throw exception if unable to delete the temp file.